# get source and aggregated data in postgresql

Tags: sql, postgresql

I have the following query:

```
SELECT round(cast(estimated_memusage as numeric), 2) as x,
       memusage as y
FROM measures_predictions
```

And I want also to get the minimum and maximum of each column.

Is there a way to build a query that return the first select above , and the min,max , without having to run two select over the same data (one normal, one grouped), is it possible to store the data temporary, making the group, and sending both at the end as result ?

Answer (score 0):

You can use below method

```
SELECT 
    round(cast(estimated_memusage as numeric),2) as x
  , memusage as y
  , min(ColumnName) over(partition by Columns) as Min 
  , max(ColumnName) over(partition by Columns) as Max FROM measures_predictions
```

Answer (score 0):

[Window functions](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/static/functions-window.html):

```
select
    round(cast(estimated_memusage as numeric), 2) as x,
    memusage as y,
    min(estimated_memusage) over() as min_estimated_memusage,
    min(memusage) over () as min_memusage,
    max(estimated_memusage) over() as max_estimated_memusage,
    max(memusage) over () as max_memusage
from measures_predictions
```